# Angularjs Pagination Index Issue?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, pagination

Here i am trying to change index on paging ,The problem is index was showing same for every page in paging so i want to be change it usually .
Here i have plunker link [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UNKbiAmGXPMNFNg38HQd?p=preview)

```
<li class="" ng-repeat="datalist in datalists | pagination: curPage * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize">
     <div>
       {{$index+1}}
       <span>{{ datalist.name }} </span>
       <span>
         {{ datalist.age }}
         </span>
         <span>{{ datalist.designation }}</span>
         </div> 
 </li>



<div class="pagination pagination-centered" ng-show="datalists.length">
<ul class="pagination-controle pagination">
 <li>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="curPage == 0"
 ng-click="curPage=curPage-1"> &lt; PREV</button>
 </li>
 <li>
 <span>Page {{curPage + 1}} of {{ numberOfPages() }}</span>
 </li>
 <li>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
 ng-disabled="curPage >= datalists.length/pageSize - 1"
 ng-click="curPage = curPage+1">NEXT &gt;</button>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here index should be same for every page but it was showing fresh numbers for second page

.js file

```
 $scope.curPage = 0;
 $scope.pageSize = 3;
 $scope.numberOfPages = function() {
                return Math.ceil($scope.datalists.length / $scope.pageSize);
            };

angular.module('sampleapp').filter('pagination', function()
{
 return function(input, start)
 {
  start = +start;
  return input.slice(start);
 };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `$index` just keeps track of the repeated items index *after* any filters have been applied.

Try changing `{{$index+1}}` to `{{$index + 1 + (curPage * pageSize)}}` as a workaround.

[Updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TrqesJHMKg9bOnunxdAc?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @machadevendher You're welcome. If this answer resolved your problem you can always mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

for me, in angular, it worked as follows

```
    index = (index) + (this.currentPage  - 1) * pageSize;
```

you can use this one if if index is starting from 1

```
    index = (index + 1) + (this.currentPage  - 1) * pageSize;
```